# Customer Email registration

Tags: magento-1.8, onepage-checkout

We have multistore setup environment in our application, and we enabled onepage checkout.
    On French site
    If customer is registered in the onepage checkout,customer registration confirmation email is going in English, it supposed to go in French, but Order confirmation is going in French.